# Threading a large amount of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I loop that will loop about 20000 times. Each time it loops, I create a new thread. The thread basically calls one method. The method is rather slow it takes four seconds to complete. It goes out and scrapes some page(which we have permission to scrape). I add a one second delay in the loop which would make sure only 4 pages are being scrapped at once. My question what happens to that thread once the method is completed?

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Thread t = new Thread(() => scraping(asin.Trim(), sku.Trim()));
t.Start();
```

Comment: Are you using a `ThreadPool` or not? That will determine how the thread is handled upon completing its work.

Comment: @Yuck I am not I will update my post to include a bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question what happens to that thread once the method is completed?

It will get destroyed as soon as the method completes.

That being said, this is not an ideal approach.  You should use the `ThreadPool` to avoid creating many threads.

Instead of using `new Thread`, consider using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to start off the task.

In addition, if you're using .NET 4, you can use `Parallel.ForEach` to loop through your entire collection concurrently.  This will use the ThreadPool (by default) to schedule all of your tasks.

Finally, you probably should eliminate the `Thread.Sleep` in your loop - it will just slow down the overall operation, and probably not provide you any gains (once you've switched to using the ThreadPool).

Comment: Just a guess here but since the work is against a remote server he's probably throttling the threads to prevent from abusing the web host.

Comment: @Yuck: It's possible - though there's not enough information to know for sure.  In that case, there may still be a better approach than Thread.Sleep...

Answer (score 2):

It exits and gets destroyed.
Maybe you'd be more interested in using a ThreadPool instead and set their maximum thread count to 4?

It will reuse the same threads for doing your task, as constructing new threads involves allocating new memory for their stacks, especially if you're doing that 20000 times, it might be one of your bottlenecks.

Comment: I am not sure if I want to use ThreadPool. The bottleneck is really by 30 Mbps Internet connections.

Comment: +1, I'll be back after the reset...blew all my votes already today!

Comment: @Joe - Even so, asking the runtime to spawn and destroy so many threads is going to put a severe beating on whatever hardware is hosting the application. Your problem seems well-defined to the point that you can make that optimization.

Answer (score 1):

It gets collected and discarded by the operating system.  You might be better off with [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx).  This will re-use threads so you don't have to incur the setup/teardown cost 20000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edited post, the thread will be destroyed and its resources garbage collected. As @Karim has also mentioned.

If you were using a `ThreadPool` it would be returned to the pool. If you know exactly how many threads you plan to keep active at any given time you could create a pool with that number to save some overhead.